# Toggle a hover opacity

Tags: jquery

How can I revert a hover opacity effect on `mouseout`? I can get my hover effect to happen without any problems, but I can't seem to undo it's effect.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3jeezjrb/

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:15px">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-push-3">
        <div class="list-group">
            <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Hello, World</a>
            <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Goodbye, Earth</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(".list-group-item").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0.5"});
});
```

I would definitely like to do this effect in JQuery, and not in pure CSS, as I need to add additional functionality afterwards (text overlay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the second param of `hover`. This will run when `mouseout` of the element.

```
$(".list-group-item").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "opacity": "0.5"
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "opacity": "1"
    });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/3jeezjrb/1/

I'd suggest you to use `css` rather than `jQuery`:

```
.list-group-item:hover {
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/3jeezjrb/2/

Answer (score 1):

Use the mouseleave callback which is the second argument to hover()

```js
$(".list-group-item").hover(function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({
    "opacity": "0.5"
  });
}, function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({
    "opacity": 1
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" style="padding-top:15px">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-push-3">
    <div class="list-group">
      <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Hello, World</a>
      <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Goodbye, Earth</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You can also use teh shorten version like

```
$(".list-group-item").hover(function (e) {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "opacity": e.type=='mouseenter' ? .5 : 1
    });
});
```

```js
$(".list-group-item").hover(function(e) {
  $(this).stop().animate({
    "opacity": e.type == 'mouseenter' ? .5 : 1
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row" style="padding-top:15px">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-push-3">
    <div class="list-group">
      <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Hello, World</a>
      <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Goodbye, Earth</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```